# property location in qml

Tags: qml, qt-quick

I have error

> ReferenceError: redRow is not defined

on this code:

```
Repeater {
            property int redRow: 0
            ...
            Image {
                ...
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.bottomMargin: height / 16 + height * redRow
                ...
            }
```

if i put
`property int redRow: 0`

in the begin of file - all right, why i don't have a opportunity put this in Repeater element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in the repeater but you have to reference this variable by the **id** of repeater:

```
Repeater {
  id: repeater //add id to the repeater this can be any unique identifier
  property int redRow: 0
  ...
  Image {
    ...
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.bottomMargin: height / 16 + height * repeater.redRow //reference repeaters property
    ...
  }
}
```